# One or more undefined variables: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_ssh_host'

Tags: openstack, ansible

I am trying to install Openstack using Ansible AIO, I ran `bootstrap-ansible.sh`, `bootstrap-aio.sh` scripts and updated `openstack_user_config.yml, user_variables.yml` files, then started `run-playbook.sh` script, it failed with following error:

> TASK: [openstack_hosts | Drop hosts file entries script] *********************
>
> fatal: [**.**.**.**] => {'msg': "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: One or more undefined variables: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_ssh_host'", 'failed': True}
>
> fatal: [**.**.**.**] => {'msg': "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: One or more undefined variables: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_ssh_host'", 'failed': True}

Can you please help to find where the issue occurs and how to fix ?

Comment: You might want to ask on the `#openstack-ansible` channel on irc (as described in the [README](https://github.com/openstack/openstack-ansible/blob/master/README.rst)).

Comment: What version of Ansible are you running? `ansible_ssh_host` has been deprecated in later versions of Ansible and is now, instead, `ansible_host`.

Comment: I am using `ansible 1.9.4` .

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this same problem on my Docker actually :)

The `'dict object'` is referring to the dictionary object that was created from the `user_variables.yml` file (possibly because the Ansible compiler uses Python, but I'm not sure).

Basically, the `'ansible_ssh_host'` must be an inner field of a top level object in the `user_variables.yml` that is either being set incorrectly or called incorrectly.

To fix your problem:

1. Check if the value of `'ansible_ssh_host'` actually exists. (For me, I was doing `host : "a.b.c"` when I should have been doing `host : "a.b.x.c"`.
2. Check if `'ansible_ssh_host'` is spelled correctly.
3. Check if the `user_variables.yml` has no syntax errors: "---" at the top, outer level object with no whitespaces, inner level pairing start with 2 whitespaces, any outside called variables use the syntax `var : "{{a.b.x.c}}"`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where I was pulling secrets from Hashicorp Vault.
All secrets except the one were working and I was getting `'dict object' has no attribute 'git'`
Problem was the secret was in `kebab-case` instead of `snake_case`.

Ansible did not like this at all and it took me forever to catch it.